# How to I create columns that are named based on the results of a groupby and matching another condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create three new columns ("Product 1 Price", "Product 2 Price", and "Product 3 Price") from an existing column "Product Price". The order of the product numbers is important and is based on three existing values in the dataframe (columns Product 1, Product 2, and Product 3).

Here is how the dataframe currently looks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Product Name','Product Price','Campaign Name','Campaign Start Date','Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'])
df.loc[0] = ['Apples',5,'Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas']
df.loc[1] = ['Mangos',15,'Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas']
df.loc[2] = ['Bananas',10,'Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas']
df.loc[3] = ['Guava',9,'Fall','2023-10-01','Guava','Apples',np.nan]
df.loc[4] = ['Apples',7,'Fall','2023-10-01','Guava','Apples',np.nan]
```

| Product Name | Product Price | Campaign Name | Campaign Start Date | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 5 | Summer | 2023-06-01 | Mangos | Apples | Bananas |
| Mangos | 15 | Summer | 2023-06-01 | Mangos | Apples | Bananas |
| Bananas | 10 | Summer | 2023-06-01 | Mangos | Apples | Bananas |
| Guava | 9 | Fall | 2023-10-01 | Guava | Apples | NaN |
| Apples | 7 | Fall | 2023-10-01 | Guava | Apples | NaN |

I need to create a column for each product's price, based on the specific campaign's price. For example, Apples are $5 in the Summer campaign but $7 in the Fall campaign.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Campaign Name','Campaign Start Date','Product 1','Product 2','Product 3','Product 1 Price','Product 2 Price','Product 3 Price'])
df2.loc[0] = ['Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas',15,5,10]
df2.loc[1] = ['Fall','2023-10-01','Guava','Apples',np.nan,9,7,np.nan]
```

| Campaign Name | Campaign Start Date | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 1 Price | Product 2 Price | Product 3 Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Summer | 2023-06-01 | Mangos | Apples | Bananas | 15 | 5 | 10.0 |
| Fall | 2023-10-01 | Guava | Apples | NaN | 9 | 7 | NaN |

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I've tried a pivot table

```
df.pivot(index='Campaign Name',columns='Product Name',values='Product Price').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

But this doesn't return the columns labeled by Product 1/2/3, which is how I need them for later in my analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data is already, in a way, wide-form. Here's one idea: you can track the product by comparing the product name with the product list, then get the product prices by the enumeration. Then you can join and groupby:

```
mask = df.iloc[:,-3:].eq(df['Product Name'],axis=0)
df.join(mask.where(mask).add_suffix(' Price')
        .mul(df['Product Price'], axis=0)
).iloc[:,2:].groupby(['Campaign Name', 'Campaign Start Date'], as_index=False).first()
```

---

Another idea is to view the table as long form and try to identify the Product enumeration for each row, then pivot:

```
mask = df.iloc[:,-3:].eq(df['Product Name'],axis=0)

pd.crosstab(index=[df['Campaign Name'], df['Campaign Start Date']], 
             columns=df.iloc[:,-3:].where(mask).stack().index.get_level_values(1),
             values=df['Product Price'],
             aggfunc='first'
            )
```

Output:

```
  Campaign Name Campaign Start Date Product 1 Product 2 Product 3  Product 1 Price  Product 2 Price  Product 3 Price
0          Fall          2023-10-01     Guava    Apples       NaN              9.0              7.0              NaN
1        Summer          2023-06-01    Mangos    Apples   Bananas             15.0              5.0             10.0
```

Comment: This was informative, thanks!! It is 10 times better my naive solution ! =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Product Name','Product Price','Campaign Name','Campaign Start Date','Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'])
df.loc[0] = ['Apples',5,'Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas']
df.loc[1] = ['Mangos',15,'Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas']
df.loc[2] = ['Bananas',10,'Summer','2023-06-01','Mangos','Apples','Bananas']
df.loc[3] = ['Guava',9,'Fall','2023-10-01','Guava','Apples',np.nan]
df.loc[4] = ['Apples',7,'Fall','2023-10-01','Guava','Apples',np.nan]

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Campaign Name','Campaign Start Date','Product 1','Product 2','Product 3','Product 1 Price','Product 2 Price','Product 3 Price'])

# Iterate over unique campaigns with itertuples()
for campaign_name, campaign_date in df[['Campaign Name', 'Campaign Start Date']].drop_duplicates().itertuples(index=False):
    # Filter rows for the current campaign
    campaign_df = df[(df['Campaign Name'] == campaign_name) & (df['Campaign Start Date'] == campaign_date)]
    new_row = {'Campaign Name': campaign_name, 'Campaign Start Date': campaign_date}
    
    for product_num in ['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3']:
        product_name = campaign_df[product_num].iloc[0]  
        # Filter the DataFrame to find rows with the same product name and get the price values
        product_price = campaign_df[campaign_df['Product Name'] == product_name]['Product Price'].values
        # Set the 'Product X' columns
        new_row[product_num] = product_name
        # Set the 'Product X Price' columns (NaN if not found)
        new_row[f'{product_num} Price'] = product_price[0] if len(product_price) > 0 else np.nan
    # Append the row to df_new
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)

df_new
```

Output:

```
Campaign Name Campaign Start Date Product 1 Product 2 Product 3 Product 1 Price Product 2 Price Product 3 Price
       Summer          2023-06-01    Mangos    Apples  Bananas               15               5              10            
         Fall          2023-10-01     Guava    Apples      NaN                9               7             NaN
```